# Html not working in php at opera single colum view

Tags: php, html, cross-browser, opera

I am new to php. My site html not working in opera single column view/mobile view. If I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` then html is working but then

```
$_SESSION['']; 
header(");
```

in php code is not working.
How I can solve this problem? Please give me solution.

Comment: Please describe in detail your problem and what you have done so far to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.